# ¿Cómo darle formato a un String el tipo de Hora en TimeStamp?

Tags: java, oracle, timestamp, microservices

Tengo una tabla en Oracle que tiene los campos HORA_INICIO Y HORA_FINAL que son de tipo *TIMESTAMP (6)*
al mapear la entidad en Java las puse de tipo String, ya que en el query que arme para tarer los datos de la base, esos campos los puse asi, ya que en la vista se debe mostrar la hora en este formato 12:04

> TO_CHAR(CE.HORA_INICIO, 'HH24:MI')

debo de hacer un Update a la tabla, y lo que recibo del front es la hora en este formato (12:04) y no me deja insertarla asi,
como puedo transformar esa fecha que me llega del front al formato Timestamp para que me deje insertar sin prblemas??

Intente concatenar, pero el resultado solo se pinta asi

> PRUEBA HORA    01/01/00 12:04

```
      @Override
      public void updateControl(ControlEntity entidad, String id) {
        try {

            ControlEntity exec = repository.findQueryById(id);

            if (entidad.getHoraInicio() != "") {
                exec.setHoraInicio(entidad.getHoraInicio());
            }
            if (entidad.getHoraFinal() != null) {
                exec.setHoraFinal(entidad.getHoraFinal());
            }
            
            String aux="01/01/00 ".concat(entidad.getHoraInicio().trim());
            System.out.println("PRUEBA HORA    " +aux);
            

            repository.save(exec);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for  Data");

        }

    }
```

al cosultar la base, muestra este formato en el campo HORA_INICIO Y HORA_FINAL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te puede lograrse con la funcion to_date

```
select TO_DATE('13:04','HH24:MI') from dual;
```

intenta poner eso en tu insert o update:

```
TO_DATE('13:04','HH24:MI')
```

Comment: es que el insert lo hago con el metodo save

Comment: es jpa o hibernate???

Comment: Estoy utilizando jpa

Comment: No se jpa pero si hibernate, y en hibernate se podia hacer algo como esto: `SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);` No se puede hacer eso en jpa??